# Fast matching tuples based on condition

Tags: algorithm, match

I am looking a fast algorithm for the following problem.

A rule is represented by a conjunction of clauses about tuples. A clause specifies a relation between two tuple items. For example `T(1)[2] = T(3)[1]` means: `the second item in the first tuple must be equal to the first one in the third`.

So a rule could be: `T(1)[2] = T(3)[1] AND T(1)[1] > T(2)[1]`

Generic rule:

- Clause: `(T(j)[i] op T(k)[l])`
- Condition: `Clause (AND Clause)*`
- Operators supported: `=`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`

The algorithm receives such a rule and a list of tuples in the form where each item is a number:

```
(i11 i12 ... i1n)
...
(ik1 ik2 ... ikm)
```

Tuples are of different length and their number is unknown. Tuples in the list can be in any order.

The algorithm will output all the combinations of tuples from input that match the rule.

Example:

Rule: `T(1)[1] = T(2)[1] AND T(1)[3]>T(3)[1]`

Tuples:

```
`(1 2 3 4)`   T1
`(3 2 4)'     T2
`(4)`         T3
`(1 5 3 6 7)` T4
```

Will output the following combinations:

- `T(1): T1, T(2): T4, T(3): T2`
- `T(1): T4, T(2): T1, T(3): T2`

Basically it will identify which tuples can substitute each T(i) so that it rule is true.

Is there a well known algorithm for doing this fast? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

A

Comment: the rule `T(1)[3]>T(3)[1]` should be `T(1)[3]>=T(3)[1]` otherwise there is no solution.

Comment: For the love of Dijkstra use zero-based indexing [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to **list** all possible assignments, versus counting the number of them, for example, which might be easier (though I don't think so), the only way to go is probably implementing a [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) solution.

**EDIT:** Specifically, since there are `N!` permutations (where `N` is the number of tuples) of the original list which might satisfy the constraints (in the worst case), and you need to list those, an upper bound of `O(N!)` is tight.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as a wrapper for the [`constraint`](http://labix.org/python-constraint) module. Here's a solution for the example from your question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from constraint import AllDifferentConstraint, Problem

number_of_variables = 3
variables = ["T(%d)" % i for i in range(1, number_of_variables+1)]
possible_values = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 2, 4), (4,), (1, 5, 3, 6, 7)]

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(variables, possible_values)
# each tuple should occur only once in the solution
problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), variables)
# T(1)[1] = T(2)[1] rule
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: len(a) > 0 and len(b) > 0 and a[0] == b[0],
                      "T(1) T(2)".split())
# T(1)[3] >= T(3)[1] rule 
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: len(a) > 2 and len(b) > 0 and a[2] >= b[0],
                      "T(1) T(3)".split()) # implicit AND

short_names = dict((val, "T%d" % i) for i, val in enumerate(possible_values, 1))
for solution in problem.getSolutionIter():
    print ", ".join("%s: %s" % (variable, short_names[value])
                    for variable, value in sorted(solution.iteritems()))
```

#### Output

```
T(1): T4, T(2): T1, T(3): T2
T(1): T1, T(2): T4, T(3): T2
```

You can combine the rules into the single constraint:

```
# T(1)[1] = T(2)[1] AND T(1)[3] >= T(3)[1]
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b, c: (len(a) > 2 and b and c and
                                       a[0] == b[0] and a[2] >= c[0]),
                      variables)
```

To install the `constraint` module, type:

$ pip install http://labix.org/download/python-constraint/python-constraint-1.1.tar.bz2

Comment: Here's a variant that generates constraints from a rule such as `T(1)[1] = T(2)[1] AND T(1)[3] >= T(3)[1]` automatically https://gist.github.com/35a2fac1255f23f57dea

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something similar to the Beta network in a Rete algorithm http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.4551&rep=rep1&type=pdf